# How to resolve Access Control Exception

Tags: servlets, applet

What replaced applets?  Was it servlets?

I ask this since many people say don't use applets. Is it due to java.io. FilePermission read errors?

Comment: *"Is it due to java.io. FilePermission read errors?"* No. They could be solved by digitally signing the code and enticing the user into approving the code when prompted. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: Thanks, I guess not a good question on my part, sorry. 

I was using a very old book, and now understand things like JavaFX replaced applets and swing and for web development we have jsp and servlets and spring.